# How do I use my PS4 skins on my Nintendo Switch copy of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4, nintendo-switch

When I go into the in-game Minecraft store on both my PS4 and Switch I'm unable to use skins from either.

For example, I purchased one of the Star Wars packs on my PS4 a couple of years ago and, even though both systems are connected to my Microsoft account, I can not use them on my Switch.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Minecraft PS4 Bedrock FAQ](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360037725571-Minecraft-for-PlayStation-TM-4-FAQ), some content does not carry over to bedrock edition, and so it will not be available on other platforms and, as other people found that star wars pack does not carry over ([PlayStation community post on the same problem](https://community.playstation.com/content/pdc/us/en_US/pdc-communities/support/games-services.topic.html/star_wars_skin_pack-rtfM.html)), I think that this is the case.

> WILL DOWNLOADABLE CONTENT I CURRENTLY OWN TRANSFER OVER TO THE NEW VERSION OF MINECRAFT?
>
> > Most existing downloadable content will be transferable from Minecraft: PS4™ Edition to the new version of Minecraft. However, some content may not be available to use on the new version and some content may only be used on your PS4™.
>
> I OWN MINECRAFT: PS4™ EDITION AND I’VE BOUGHT PREVIOUS DOWNLOADABLE CONTENT. HOW DO I GET IT TO SYNC TO MINECRAFT?
>
> > Log into Minecraft on your PS4™ and you’ll be automatically granted the entitlements for that downloadable content in the latest version.